# DSN-less ODBC connect string for legacy Sybase Adaptive Server Anywhere

Tags: vb6, odbc, oledb, sybase-asa

This is a failed response to this article: [Sybase, VB and ADO](http://www.vbrad.com/article.aspx?id=94)

I just did a VB6 project connecting to a legacy ASA 7 database. After failing to use ASAProv OLEDB provider altogether (for one reason or another) and much research, here is the connect string for OLEDB Provider for ODBC shim for a DSN-less ODBC driver connection:

`Provider=MSDASQL.1;Driver={Adaptive Server Anywhere 7.0};CommLinks=TCPIP,SharedMemory;EngineName=<database_name>;UID=DBA;PWD=SQL`

where `<database_name>` is the instance name dbeng7.exe is running the db under. Check the engine log for 'Starting database "`<database_name>`"'.

You can find all the valid property names for an ODBC connect string by creating a system DSN, adjust settings and inspecting values `HKLM\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBC.INI\<system_dsn>` key.

The available ODBC drivers that can be used under Driver property of the MSDASQL provider connect string are subkeys of `HKLM\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBCINST.INI`

Apparently Sybase login passwords are case insensitive which I find quite hilarious.

cheers
`</wqw>`

Comment: Case-sensitivity (of all strings) is a database option for ASA. The default is to have a case-insensitive db. It looks like the dbinit option is "-c" to create a case-sensitive db.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow, I actually wrote that article in the last millennium, I believe.

Let me take this point by point.

1. OLEDB provider works fine for it, I remember using them from back in the day.  Just follow instructions here: http://www.vbrad.com/article.aspx?id=81 on how to create a connection string.
2. For ODBC, going to http://www.connectionstrings.com/ has never failed me.  They got connection strings up wazoo.